# How does Nginx support http and https back-end apps?

Tags: https, nginx, glassfish

[image]

Does anybody have experience about this kind of architecture?
Note: GalssFish2.x on 1.11 supports SSL itself.

Comment: This diagram doesn't make much sense out of the actual context... What do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define multiple separate upstream servers and proxy to them based on `location` block.

```
http {
    upstream backend1 {
        server 1.2.3.4:80;
    }
    upstream backend2 {
        server 5.6.7.8:80;
    }

    server {
        [...]
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend1;
        }

        location /flow {
            proxy_pass https://backend2;
        }
    }
}
```

This example is simplified a lot, of course.
Check out [the wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/Modules) and [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/).